# How to get the the value of brand property?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to retrieve the value of the property brand but what i get is undefined..

My code

```
temp = [{}];

for (var k = 0; k < localStorage.length; k++) {
    const shoes = localStorage.getItem('shoe' + k);
    if (shoes !== null) {
        this.temp.push(localStorage.getItem('shoe' + k));
    }
}

console.log(this.temp[1].brand);
console.log(this.temp);
```

**Console:**
[image: Console]

**LocalStorage:**
[image: LocalStorage]

Comment: localStorage obj is empty therefore you get undefined

Comment: Doesn’t localStorage.get not return a string? You might have to do a JSON.parse first.

Comment: As you can see with console.log(this.temp) i am getting back the array...but i cannot print the value of the brand...only the array..